# two-way, repeated-measures ANOVA for mixed design in python?

Tags: python, statistics, anova

Does anybody know of a python function for performing two-way, repeated-measures ANOVAs for mixed experimental design (2 groups, 4 conditions)?  I looked at scipy.statistics, but they don't seem to have what I need (unless I missed it...)

Thanks

Comment: maybe check on the mathoverflow exchange site, they might have some suggestions

Comment: I had no idea mathoverflow existed.  Thank you!

Comment: not sure if it is called that but there is one for math, and just about everything else lol

Comment: @GregBrown: actually it's just called "math". math.stackexchange.com

Comment: mathoverflow is a distinct stackexchange type site that is different from math.stackexchange.com, but both basically function in the same way and many questions are cross-posted between them. stats.stackexchange.com should be much better for this question than either mathoverflow or math.stackexchange.com